# How to implement the multiselect combo box in EXT JS

Tags: extjs

I want to implement the multiselect combo box in my program. Means If I will select multiple names through check box then all selected names will be fall in that combo with comma separated... I want a sample example... Could you please help me..

Comment: I think if you focus on your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620911/how-to-implement-the-multiselect-listbox-using-ext-js) first, you might be able to figure this one out also.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?69090-Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect-as-seen-on-facebook-and-hotmail) user extension.  [Examples](http://technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examples3.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use combobox plugin Ext.ux.Andrie.Select. For demo :
http://www.andrei.neculau.home.ro/extjs2/ux.Andrie.Select/Select_test.htm

Comment: This one shows errors on the multi-select part of the demo once you have selected one or more entries.

Answer (score 0):

I have Implemented Checkcombo without using any extra plugin or file.

You just need to add image [checkbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbDUO.gif) in css

And CSS Reference

```
 .chkbox {
 height: 13px;
 width: 13px;
 background: transparent url(please see checkbox image) no-repeat 0px 0px;
 float: left;
 margin: 4px 5px 0 0;
 }
.x-boundlist-selected .chkbox {
   background-position: 0 -13px;
}
```

See the demo in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/neel2911/bbkmw8p1/)